# Trouble inserting multiple lists into a single MySQL query in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert two lists into a MySQL table to make up a single row. I can successfully do this by referencing each index of the lists into a MySQL query, but I'd like to be able to just drop the lists into the query without having to type out each and every index.

Here is the snippet of my code that works (in Python 3.5):

```
with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
   add_accounts_query = "INSERT INTO accounts(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) \
                         VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}')"
   try:
       cursor.execute(add_accounts_query.format(a_list[0], a_list[1], a_list[2], b_list[0], b_list[1], b_list[2]))
```

Here's what I've tried that doesn't work:

```
try:
    cursor.execute(add_accounts_query.format(
        ", ".join(list(map(str, a_list))) + ", " + ", ".join(list(map(str, b_list)))))
```

I've also tried many variations of the above by removing the comma, adding apostrophes on the outsides, etc but nothing seems to work. I keep getting an "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Please note that the values in the list may be a string or integer or None.

Comment: have you tried string substitution by means of % ? that works in most cases and is a lot less messy

Comment: Doesn't `.format(*a_list)` do what you want?

Comment: @rai yes I have but the newer versions of Python insist that `.format` is better/more efficient

Comment: @Barmar yes that does work when I make it `.format(*a_list, *b_list)`

Based on what I asked, this is the question I was looking for so if you mark it as an answer I will accept. I do like the idea, however, of using a class to model my tables so thank you for you answer as well @jeremija

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [argument list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to turn a list into separate function arguments.

```
cursor.execute(add_accounts_query.format(*a_list, *b_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, mapping a list to columns is a bad idea. Every time you decide
to add a new element to your list, you will need to add a new column.

If you have data for a single account, then you'd be better of by using a
class to define the data model of your Account like:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6):
        self.column1 = column1
        self.column2 = column2
        self.column3 = column3
        self.column4 = column4
        self.column5 = column5
        self.column6 = column6
```

Then you can instantiate it like:

```
account = Account('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6')
```

And you can format the query:

```
query = add_account_query.format(
    account.column1,
    account.column2,
    account.column3,
    account.column4,
    account.column5
    account.column6)
cursor.execute(query)
```

If you wish to automatically map domain your model to the database columns,
you can take a look into ORM libraries such as
[peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/). For a list of Python ORMs
check [this link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/db/).

Then you could be able to [define your account model like](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#using-mysql):

```
from peewee import *

mysql_db = MySQLDatabase('my_database',
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='myuser',
    password='mypass')

class Account(Model):
    column1 = CharField()
    column2 = CharField()
    column3 = CharField()
    column4 = CharField()
    column5 = CharField()
    column6 = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = mysql_db
        db_table = 'accounts'
```

Then [storing the data in](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html) your database is as easy as:

```
account = Account.create(
    column1='val1',
    column2='val2',
    column3='val3',
    column4='val4',
    column5='val5',
    column6='val6')
```

Most probably you'd also want an ID column in your data model.